# Function not firing in Context call

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to run a function within the useEffect hook, so that on screen load it automatically calls the context and works out what to do.

But for whatever reason, the function just isn't firing. The screen loads successfully and renders, no errors, but just doesn't do anything.

Here's my component I'm calling the context from:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';

const LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const { userSignedIn } = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    userSignedIn()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <ActivityIndicator style={styles.indicator} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

And my context file:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { navigate } from '../navigationRef';

import { Magic } from '@magic-sdk/react-native';
const m = new Magic('API key');

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const userSignedIn = () => {
    return async () => {
    // Call Magic logged in
      const loggedIn = await m.user.isLoggedIn();
      console.log(loggedIn)
      // If user logged in, save details to user, and redirect to dashboard
      if (loggedIn === true) {
        const { issuer, email } = await m.user.getMetaData();
          console.log(issuer)
          console.log(email)
          setUser([issuer, email])
          navigate('authorisedFlow')
        // If user not logged in, redirect to login flow
      } else {
          console.log(userSignedIn)
          console.log("Not signed in.")
          navigate('loginFlow')
        }
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, userSignedIn }}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Feels a simple one.. But can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an `async` function when calling `userSignedIn` so the following should work for you by making `userSignedIn` itself `async` to work for those `await` calls inside.

```
const userSignedIn = async () => {
    // Call Magic logged in
      const loggedIn = await m.user.isLoggedIn();
      console.log(loggedIn)
      // If user logged in, save details to user, and redirect to dashboard
      if (loggedIn === true) {
        const { issuer, email } = await m.user.getMetaData();
          console.log(issuer)
          console.log(email)
          setUser([issuer, email])
          navigate('authorisedFlow')
        // If user not logged in, redirect to login flow
      } else {
          console.log(userSignedIn)
          console.log("Not signed in.")
          navigate('loginFlow')
        }
  };
```

Comment: Hey - I thought it would work too, but it doesn't. Nothing happens upon the screen loading. No console log or anything.